# Is it possible for a Chrome Extension to screen grab from an incognito window?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a screen recorder as a Chrome Extension. The idea is that the recorder can log all mouse and keyboard events, and also store a stream of images from the browser client window. I want to do all of the recording from an incognito window. So far, I'm not managing. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. User just has to allow incognito mode.

Here are the steps below to get this done:
1. In chrome://extension find your extension press details
2. Then Find the section that says allow in incognito.

Just turn it on, this will work.